# Python - Convert a 2-column file into 10-column

Tags: python

Dear all) I have an issue which is quite difficult for me because I just start doing Python. So, lets imagine we have a 2-column file like:

```
col_1 col_2
1     6 
2     7
3     8
4     9
5     10
```

I need to perform several conversions (using diferent equations) that will create additional columns (basically, about 15 columns at all). But I am not sure how to wrap it as a readable and logical code.

Let me show you my thoughts (I am sure they are so wrong, but I really hope your eyes won't start bleeding:)). First of all, is an idea of using class for this issue a proper one? Or just functions?

```
INPUT = 'input.txt'
OUTPUT = 'output.txt'

def col_3_function():
    with open(INPUT, 'r') as reader, open(OUTPUT, 'a') as writer:
        for line in reader:
            global col_3
            column = line.strip().split()
            col_1 = float(column[1])
            col_2 = float(column[2])
            col_3 = (col_1 + col_2)

def col_4_function():
    with open(INPUT, 'r') as reader, open(OUTPUT, 'a') as writer:
        for line in reader:
            global col_4
            column = line.strip().split()
            col_1 = float(column[1])
            col_2 = float(column[2])
            col_4 = col_3 - col_2
            print(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, sep='\t', file=writer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    col_4_function()
```

And so on until there will be a needed amount of columns.

There are a couple of stumbling blocks for me:

- It doesn't work even in this easy version:)
- As far as I know, using a lot of global variables is kind of a moveton.
- Every next column should use data nor only from columns 1 and 2 but from previously created in column_3, column_4 and so on.
- Also I don't like the repeatness in every function. Not a Python approach.
- Should I use class? Or just functions? What should it be like?

There are a lot of other toughs for me but I should start from the most general.

I understand this is a pretty general and big issue but that is so important for me. I would be really thankful for your thoughts and ideas. Really.

Comment: Please elaborate on "It doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic approche. It does not handle the first line in your file (I don't know how you want to name your columns, so I didn't do it :))

```
INPUT = "toto.txt"
OUTPUT = "titi.txt"

def col3_fn(columns):
    """ Just sum column 1 and 2. Used as generator of column 3 content """
    return int(columns[0]) + int(columns[1])

def col4_fn(columns):
    """ Difference between column 2 and 3. Used as generator of column 4 content """
    return int(columns[1]) - int(columns[2])

# List of functions used for column generation.
# You can add as much as you want.
functions = [col3_fn, col4_fn]

with open(INPUT, "r") as inp, open(OUTPUT, "w") as out:
    for line in inp.readlines():
        splited = line[:-1].split()

        for f in functions:
            splited.append(str(f(splited)))

        out.write("\t".join(splited) + "\n")
```

Input file (*toto.txt*):

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Output file (*titi.txt*):

```
1   1   2   -1
2   2   4   -2
3   3   6   -3
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer) However, there are a couple of unsolved issues left, first of all what, if I need data from column 3 to calculate column 4?

Comment: The result of the function associated to column 3 will be append in the `splited` list, which is given as parameter of the function associated to column 4. In the code given, you can see that the `col4_fn` function calculate the difference between column 2 and column 3.

Comment: Note that I did an edit 30 minutes ago. Maybe you had the old code which didn't implement this functionality.

Comment: Yeah, great, it works, looks like I didn't get smth previously) Thanks and great answer)

Comment: Please considere validating the answer if it was useful :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use numpy

```
import numpy as np
col1, col2 = np.loadtxt (INPUT, dtype=int, unpack=True)
col3 = col1 + col2
col4 = col3 - col2
np.savetxt (OUTPUT, np.vstack((col1, col2, col3, col4)).T, fmt='%d')
```

If you are operating on floats, you don't need the `dtype` and `fmt` arguments

Comment: Wow, it looks so easy using numpy. But for now I have not even installed it yet, however, will do it asap. Hope, it works) Thank you.